# Infinite Loop during while

Tags: c#, .net, while-loop, infinite-loop

Why is this running indefinitely and not adding days

```
var startDate = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);
var endDate = startDate.AddYears(1);

while (startDate < endDate)
{
    startDate.AddDays(1);
}
```

The goal is to loop through all the days in a year.

Thanks!

Comment: Side note: `for` loop instead of `while` looks, IMHO, more natural: `for (var date = new DateTime(year, 1, 1); date < new DateTime(year + 1, 1, 1); date = date.AddDays(1)) { ... }`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In .NET `DateTime` is immutable, so `AddDays` method just returns new date, not changes `startDate` itself.

You should assign this new value back to `startDate`:

```
startDate = startDate.AddDays(1);
```

Comment: A bit out of topic. But does `.AddDays(1)` method cover Leap years?

Comment: Surely it does. You can check it pretty easily: `var date1 = new DateTime(2016, 2, 28).AddDays(1); var date2 = new DateTime(2015, 2, 28).AddDays(1);`

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid such *pesky errors* (not assigning back `AddDays(1)` result) I suggest implementing `for` loop instead of `while`:

```
  for (var date = new DateTime(year, 1, 1); 
           date < new DateTime(year + 1, 1, 1); 
           date = date.AddDays(1)) {
    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`startDate.AddDays(1);` does not change `startDate`, so `startDate < endDate` is always true.